# Dead lock occurs even update on different fields

Tags: firebird, database-deadlocks

I have been trying to develop replication from a Firebird database to other.
I simply add a new field to tables named `replication_flag`.

My replication program starts a read committed transaction, select rows, update this `replication_flag` field of rows then then commits or rollbacks.

My production client(s) does not update this `replication_flag` field and uses read committed isolation. My only one replication client only update this `replication_flag` field and does not update any other fields.

I still see dead locks and do not understand why. How can I avoid dead locks?

Comment: The term _deadlock_ is a bit of a misnomer here, it is actually an update conflict. You might want to specify the exact transaction options you use, because in Firebird this error is more common when you use the `no_rec_version` option in combination with read committed (as opposed to `rec_version`). Also keep in mind: even though a single field was changed, this means the whole record got a new version!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thank you for your help.
So, as I understand, I should change my isolation with another one includes rec_version.
I will try it.

Comment: Just to clarify, both are read committed, but some drivers use the no_rec_version as default, which increases the chance of this error occurring.

Comment: Hi there. Hope this article helps (it's actually on Interbase 6.1 replication but as you may or may not know Firebird was built on Interbase 6.1 when it was made open source) http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27144

Comment: Mark and Ryno, thank you for your help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your replication app use a large transaction updating each record of each table. Probably, at the end, the whole database has been "locked".

You should consider using transactions by table or record packets. it's also possible to use a read-only transaction to read, and use an other transaction to write, with frequent commit, that allow other transactions to update the record.

An interesting slideshow: http://slideplayer.us/slide/1651121/